# kafka-avro-console-producer throwing org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Cannot parse <null> schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to send a avro message by registering the schema in confluent schema-registry:

```
[appuser@schema-registry bin]$ ./kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic t.lower.case --property schema.registry.url='localhost:8081' --property value.schema= '\
{
>   "namespace": "com.thebigscale",
>   "type": "record",
>   "name": "Customer",
>   "fields": [
>     {"name": "first_name", "type":"string", "doc": "First name of the person"},
>     {"name": "last_name", "type":"string", "doc": "Last name of the person"},
>     {"name": "age", "type":"int", "doc": ""},
>     {"name": "height", "type":"double", "doc": ""},
>     {"name": "weight", "type":"double", "doc": ""},
>     {"name": "automated_emails", "type":"boolean", "default":true, "doc": ""}
>   ]
> }'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[2020-12-13 19:31:28,867] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-12-13 19:31:29,725] ERROR Could not parse Avro schema (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaProvider)
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Cannot parse <null> schema
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1595)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1394)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1382)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchema.<init>(AvroSchema.java:63)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaProvider.parseSchema(AvroSchemaProvider.java:41)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.parseSchema(SchemaMessageReader.java:160)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.getSchema(SchemaMessageReader.java:172)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.init(SchemaMessageReader.java:144)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:43)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.parseSchema(SchemaMessageReader.java:160)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.getSchema(SchemaMessageReader.java:172)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.init(SchemaMessageReader.java:144)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:43)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
[appuser@schema-registry bin]$
```

I am able to generate the java object via normal gradle plugin, so I am not sure where am I going wrong.

Comment: You have a space after `value.schema`